# Latex-url link manipulating

Tags: url, latex

I am trying to insert a link like this: https://www.bing.com/search?q=latex%20&qs=n&form=QBRE&=Search%20%7B0%7D%20for%20%7B1%7D&=Search%20work%20for%20%7B0%7D&msbsrank=6_9_File_2&sp=-1&ghc=1&pq=latex%20&sc=9-6&sk=&cvid=9E08663E21964006BFBDECC6DB1F0884 to my document using latex.

I tried this line of code:

```
\href{https://www.bing.com/search?q=latex%20&qs=n&form=QBRE&=Search%20%7B0%7D%20for%20%7B1%7D&=Search%20work%20for%20%7B0%7D&msbsrank=6_9_File_2&sp=-1&ghc=1&pq=latex%20&sc=9-6&sk=&cvid=9E08663E21964006BFBDECC6DB1F0884}{\textit{\textbf{\underline{Something Linky}}}
```

And it produced an error.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one closing `}` at the end:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}


\href{https://www.bing.com/search?q=latex%20&qs=n&form=QBRE&=Search%20%7B0%7D%20for%20%7B1%7D&=Search%20work%20for%20%7B0%7D&msbsrank=6_9_File_2&sp=-1&ghc=1&pq=latex%20&sc=9-6&sk=&cvid=9E08663E21964006BFBDECC6DB1F0884}{\textit{\textbf{\underline{Something Linky}}}}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The issue is fixed, Now I am trying to create a variable: \newcommand{\Link}{\href{https://www.bing.com/search?q=latex%20&qs=n&form=QBRE&=Search%20%7B0%7D%20for%20%7B1%7D&=Search%20work%20for%20%7B0%7D&msbsrank=6_9_File_2&sp=-1&ghc=1&pq=latex%20&sc=9-6&sk=&cvid=9E08663E21964006BFBDECC6DB1F0884}{\textit{\textbf{\underline{Something Linky}}}}} but it produced an error. any help ?

Comment: @Nour If you have a new question, please ask a new question